# Slow NVME performance on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, ssd, storage, nvme

I guess I'm missing something here, perhaps I need to do some configuration to enable my hardware full speed under Linux - here's my problem.

I recently  got this [Intel NUC 9 Extreme kit](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/190107/intel-nuc-9-extreme-kit-nuc9i9qnx.html).

I added 64 GB of RAM, and since I wanted to setup a RAID1 drive, I put two [Samsung 970 EVO 1TB M.2 NVME](https://www.samsung.com/uk/memory-storage/nvme-ssd/970-evo-nvme-m-2-ssd-1tb-mz-v7e1t0bw/) drives in it:

Since they are PCIe Gen 3 x4 devices,  **I was expecting to be able to get something close to 3 GB/s in sequential reads from a single drive and a little less than 6 GB/s from a RAID1 device**, but actual speeds disappointed me, since **I couldn't get more than 2.1 GB/s, even in RAID1.**

To test storage speed I used `dd`, like this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/test/64GB bs=1G count=64 && dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/ubuntu/evo/fill-cache bs=1G count=64 && dd if=/path/to/test/64GB of=/dev/null
64+0 record dentro
64+0 record fuori
68719476736 bytes (69 GB, 64 GiB) copied, 43,3462 s, 1,6 GB/s
64+0 record dentro
64+0 record fuori
68719476736 bytes (69 GB, 64 GiB) copied, 49,6182 s, 1,4 GB/s
134217728+0 record dentro
134217728+0 record fuori
68719476736 bytes (69 GB, 64 GiB) copied, 139,781 s, 492 MB/s
```

I run these commands 6-7 times and sequential **write speeds were less than 1.2 GB/s. Sequential read speeds were always less than 1.9 GB/s.** Running `bonnie++` I got similar results.

I did my tests booting that system from an external USB drive running Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4 and from a Fedora 33 install disk running kernel 5.8, with similar results (in Fedora speeds were even worse). I tried both with ext4 and xfs, with no appreciable difference.

Since the results are the same in RAID1 and even when I create a striped LVM volume, I guess there must be a bottleneck somewhere that prevents my hardware to run at full speed.

**The hardware seems to work fine**, since when I tried  to boot that system from an external USB disk running Windows 10, I got the expected performance:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskMark 8.0.0 x64 (C) 2007-2020 hiyohiyo
                                  Crystal Dew World: https://crystalmark.info/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes/s [SATA/600 = 600,000,000 bytes/s]
* KB = 1000 bytes, KiB = 1024 bytes

[Read]
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):  2924.425 MB/s [   2788.9 IOPS] <  2865.38 us>
  SEQ  128KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):  3523.300 MB/s [  26880.6 IOPS] <  1179.77 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T=16):  2077.373 MB/s [ 507171.1 IOPS] <  1005.95 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    53.885 MB/s [  13155.5 IOPS] <    75.87 us>

[Write]
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):  2208.972 MB/s [   2106.6 IOPS] <  3788.09 us>
  SEQ  128KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):  2117.792 MB/s [  16157.5 IOPS] <  1978.06 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T=16):  1962.843 MB/s [ 479209.7 IOPS] <  1067.32 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   130.946 MB/s [  31969.2 IOPS] <    31.13 us>

Profile: Default
   Test: 64 GiB (x5) [G: 0% (0/932GiB)]
   Mode: [Admin]
   Time: Measure 5 sec / Interval 5 sec 
   Date: 2020/12/15 10:18:14
     OS: Windows 10 Professional [10.0 Build 18363] (x64)
```

My devices are also running latest firmware.

Should I do something special on my linux system to to enable these speeds?

#### Update

Someone suggested me that **my benchmark approach with `dd` could be wrong**, and to try the benchmark feature of Gnome Disks.

I tried and got read speeds closer to the specifications, so I was doing things the wrong way. Still, write speeds are 1/4 of those I saw with CrystalDiskMark on Windows, so I'm still puzzled.

[image: Gnome Disks Benchmark]

Comment: RAID1 is mirroring. I don't have much experience with it but I don't think you would get double the speed with it. You would need RAID0, stripping, to get high speed.

Comment: I agree that RAID1 is actually slower because it is making a backup to the other drive all the time where a RAID0 has no redundancy, but it is extremely fast because the data is striped across the drives.

Comment: You're right, my fault, RAID1 doesn't work as I expected. Someone else suggested me to use Gnome Disks to benchmark the drives, and I got read results closer to the expected ones: https://imgur.com/nj0rK0V I'm updating the question accordingly. Still, write results are lower than expected.